# how to share video to gallery of iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to share a video to the iPhone gallery using `UIActivityViewController`, but it is not displaying a "Save Video" option. I did the same for an image, and it shows an option called "Save Image" which saves the image in to gallery.
I am not sure what going wrong.

```
NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abcd.samplevideo/7173355890_4.mp4"];
[sharingItems addObject:url];
 UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can any one let me know what's going wrong?

Comment: try *.mov extension instead.

Comment: you mean instead.mp4?

Comment: how can i controller video extensions?

Comment: how ever even .mov is not showing up!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the file they its easy to share

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
    NSURL *tempURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];
    [data writeToURL:tempURL atomically:YES];
    [sharingItems addObject:tempURL];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self shareSheetForMedia:sharingItems];
    });
   }];
```